# Is there a way to get the Yelp URL for a given business?

Tags: yelp

If I have information about a business, how do I go about getting the Yelp URL for that business via a script (say a Perl script for example)? For example, if I have information about "Toni's Pizza & Organic Pasta", how do I about getting the Yelp URL programmatically ( which is "http://www.yelp.com/biz/tonis-pizza-and-organic-pasta-chicago")? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Yelp API to query Yelp's servers for a particular business using HTTP requests. The downside is you must be an authenticated Yelp user which may or may not work for your purposes.

See for more details:

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/phone_api

Comment: I looked at that and it looks like you can only search by ID. What if I don't have the ID readily available? Can I search by phone number instead? How would I do that?

Comment: You could first do a search query for the region that the business is in and then search through the business list in the response for the phone number of the business you're interested in.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it they have a [phone API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/phone_api) that is what you're looking for.